# Sequelize Transaction Rollback to Specific Savepoint

Tags: javascript, transactions, sequelize.js

I'm using [managed transactions](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/transactions.html) in my project and I have a case where I'd like to use a single transaction and rollback to a specific savepoint if it fails, but always commit in the end.

For example, I want to create an `Event` and try to run an `action`. If the `action` fails, I want to rollback any db activity that occurred during the action but keep the `Event` record and subsequently update it with the result.

```js
const transaction = await sequelize.transaction();

const event = await Event.create({ ... }, { transaction });

// I want to mark the savepoint here

try {
  const action = await runAction(transaction);
  event.status = 'success';
  event.action_id = action.id;
} catch (err) {
  // This is where I want to rollback any changes since the savepoint
  event.status = 'failure';
  event.failure_message = err.message;
}

await event.save({ transaction });
await transaction.commit();
```

As far as I understand, I should be able to achieve this by creating a new transaction with the existing one, effectively marking a savepoint:

```js
const transaction = await sequelize.transaction();

const event = await Event.create({ ... }, { transaction });

const savepoint = await sequelize.transaction({ transaction });

try {
  const action = await runAction(savepoint);
  ...
} catch (err) {
  await savepoint.rollback();
  ...
}

await event.save({ transaction });
await transaction.commit();
```

However this doesn't work, and all operations using the transaction within `runAction` are still committed. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

I realized that I have a **findOrCreate** being called within `runAction`. Sequelize creates savepoints in **findOrCreate** when provided a transaction in the options.

When creating a new transaction and providing a transaction in the options, it automatically creates a savepoint [as shown here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/v5/lib/transaction.js#L41-L42). This savepoint is given an id (which is based on the index of the new savepoint on the parent) and a db query is executed to set the savepoint in the transaction. So when I ran `sequelize.transaction({ transaction });` it created a savepoint with name "transaction-id-1". Later on when **findOrCreate** is called and provided the "savepoint" transaction, it creates a savepoint with the same name "transaction-id-1", effectively overwriting the previous savepoint.

**So I should have been passing the parent transaction to `runAction` rather than `savepoint`:**

```js
const transaction = await sequelize.transaction();

const event = await Event.create({ ... }, { transaction });

const savepoint = await sequelize.transaction({ transaction });

try {
  // Pass parent transaction, rather savepoint transaction
  const action = await runAction(transaction);
  ...
} catch (err) {
  await savepoint.rollback();
  ...
}

await event.save({ transaction });
await transaction.commit();
```

Comment: How do you name the save point? I tried creating a save point this way but it doesn't seem to work.  What exactly is the 'savepoint' object at this point in your code? Is this a separate transaction or an actual mysql save point?

Comment: The way you have it written with sequelize.transaction({transaction}), this is NOT using save points, it's creating a  new transaction.  What you want to do is say {transaction:transaction} in your example so it ACTUALLY uses save points.  Hope this helps someone else! The key for the options object being passed into transaction has to say 'transaction' in order for save points to work.  ALSO note that save points only work if the system supports it, which MySQL does for example.